# SQL - Calling scripts Error SQLCMD query

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, database-migration, sqlcmd

So i have been writing a data migration script for the past few weeks and have decided it has become too long and is too hard to edit as one long script. So what i wanted to do was to split it up into individual scripts and have one script run the others.

From looking around i found that you can call each script by setting the query to run in SQLCMD mode. This does work however i am getting quite a few errors with only the first two scripts (one is a procedure):

```
-- Setting path variable
----> This will need to be changed to the correct location before running
:setvar path "Directory\DIR"

-- Create Procedures
:r $(path)\~alterFieldSize.sql

-- Call Migration Scripts
:r $(path)\~prerequisites.sql
```

Which gives me the following errors:

> Msg 154, Level 15, State 1,  Procedure alterFieldSize, Line 43 [Batch
>   Start Line 0] a USE database statement is not allowed in a procedure,
>   function or trigger.
>
> Msg 134, Level 15, State 1,  Procedure alterFieldSize, Line 81 [Batch
>   Start Line 0] The variable name '@column' has already been declared.
>   Variable names must be unique within a query batch or stored
>   procedure.
>
> Msg 134, Level 15, State 1, Procedure alterFieldSize, Line 82 [Batch
>   Start Line 0] The variable name '@table' has already been declared.
>   Variable names must be unique within a query batch or stored
>   procedure.
>
> Msg 134, Level 15, State 1, Procedure alterFieldSize, Line 83 [Batch
>   Start Line 0] The variable name '@fieldLen' has already been declared.
>   Variable names must be unique within a query batch or stored
>   procedure.
>
> Msg 154, Level 15, State 1,  Procedure alterFieldSize, Line 91 [Batch
>   Start Line 0] a USE database statement is not allowed in a procedure,
>   function or trigger.

These errors do not occur when i run the two scripts separately, or when i run the entire migration script. The alterFieldSize.sql and prerequisites.sql scripts are below:

**alterFieldSize.sql -- Procedure**

```
CREATE PROCEDURE alterFieldSize @column NVARCHAR(MAX), @table NVARCHAR(MAX), @prsColumnLen INT
AS
-- DECLARE VARIABLES
    DECLARE @sql        NVARCHAR(MAX)
    DECLARE @fieldLen   INT
    DECLARE @columnLen  INT

-- SET VARIABLES
SET     @fieldLen   = @prsColumnLen
SET     @columnLen  = (SELECT CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE COLUMN_NAME LIKE @column AND TABLE_NAME LIKE @table)
SET     @fieldLen   = CASE WHEN @columnLen > @fieldLen THEN @columnLen WHEN @fieldLen <=500 THEN @fieldLen ELSE 500 END
SET     @sql        = 'ALTER TABLE ' +@table+ ' ALTER COLUMN '+ @column + ' NVARCHAR('+cast(@fieldLen as VARCHAR(20))+')'


-- Execution
EXEC(@sql)
```

**prerequisites.sql**

```
PRINT '-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------'
PRINT '---------------------------------------------------- PREREQUISITES ----------------------------------------------------------'
PRINT '-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------'

-- CREATE COLUMNS
USE [DB1];
-- ALTER TABLE tblPerson        ADD welPersonnelID      NVARCHAR(20);
-- ALTER TABLE tblPerson        ADD aucPersonnelID      NVARCHAR(20);
-- ALTER TABLE Client           ADD welSiteID           NVARCHAR(20);
-- ALTER TABLE Client           ADD aucSiteID           NVARCHAR(20);
-- ALTER TABLE tblContact       ADD COwelPersonnelID    NVARCHAR(20);
-- ALTER TABLE tblContact       ADD COaucPersonnelID    NVARCHAR(20);
-- ALTER TABLE tblCandidate     ADD CAwelPersonnelID    NVARCHAR(20);
-- ALTER TABLE tblCandidate     ADD CAaucPersonnelID    NVARCHAR(20);
-- ALTER TABLE AM               ADD AMwelPersonnelID    NVARCHAR(20);
-- ALTER TABLE AM               ADD AMaucPersonnelID    NVARCHAR(20);
-- ALTER TABLE AM               ADD TRISID              NVARCHAR(20);
-- ALTER TABLE Job              ADD welVacancyID        NVARCHAR(20);
-- ALTER TABLE Job              ADD aucVacancyID        NVARCHAR(20);

-- ---- DB2                                 
-- USE [DB2];   
-- ALTER TABLE Sites            ADD siteID#TRIS     NVARCHAR(20);
-- ALTER TABLE personnel        ADD personID#TRIS   NVARCHAR(20);
-- ALTER TABLE personnel        ADD personStatus    NVARCHAR(20);
-- ALTER TABLE personnel        ADD titleID         int;
-- ALTER TABLE Vacancies        ADD jobID#TRIS      NVARCHAR(20);
-- ALTER TABLE Vacancies        ADD ContactID#TRIS  NVARCHAR(20);
-- ALTER TABLE Vacancies        ADD ClientID#TRIS   NVARCHAR(20);

-- ---- DB3
-- USE [DB3];   
-- ALTER TABLE Sites            ADD siteID#TRIS     NVARCHAR(20);
-- ALTER TABLE personnel        ADD personID#TRIS   NVARCHAR(20);
-- ALTER TABLE personnel        ADD personStatus    NVARCHAR(20);
-- ALTER TABLE personnel        ADD titleID         int;
-- ALTER TABLE Vacancies        ADD jobID#TRIS      NVARCHAR(20);
-- ALTER TABLE Vacancies        ADD ContactID#TRIS  NVARCHAR(20);
-- ALTER TABLE Vacancies        ADD ClientID#TRIS   NVARCHAR(20);

-- PURPOSE: Declares variables and creates columns that are used for linking

-- DECLARE VARIABLES
DECLARE @column     NVARCHAR(MAX);
DECLARE @table      NVARCHAR(MAX);
DECLARE @fieldLen   INT;
DECLARE @fieldLenA  INT;
DECLARE @fieldLenW  INT;

-- SET VARIABLES

    -- CHANGE FIELD LENGTHS
    ---- CLIENT
    USE [DB1]
    SET @fieldLenA  = (SELECT MAX(LEN(s.StreetAddress)) FROM [DB2].dbo.Sites s)
    SET @fieldLenW  = (SELECT MAX(LEN(s.StreetAddress)) FROM [DB3].dbo.Sites s)
    SET @fieldLen   = CASE WHEN @fieldLenA > @fieldLenW THEN @fieldLenA ELSE @fieldLenW END
    EXEC alterFieldSize @column = 'ClientAddress',      @table = 'Client',  @prsColumnLen = @fieldLen;

    SET @fieldLenA  = (SELECT MAX(LEN(s.PostalAddress)) FROM [DB2].dbo.Sites s)
    SET @fieldLenW  = (SELECT MAX(LEN(s.PostalAddress)) FROM [DB3].dbo.Sites s)
    SET @fieldLen   = CASE WHEN @fieldLenA > @fieldLenW THEN @fieldLenA ELSE @fieldLenW END
    EXEC alterFieldSize @column = 'ClientPOAddress',    @table = 'Client',  @prsColumnLen = @fieldLen;

    SET @fieldLenA  = (SELECT MAX(LEN(s.Phone))         FROM [DB2].dbo.Sites s)
    SET @fieldLenW  = (SELECT MAX(LEN(s.Phone))         FROM [DB3].dbo.Sites s)
    SET @fieldLen   = CASE WHEN @fieldLenA > @fieldLenW THEN @fieldLenA ELSE @fieldLenW END
    EXEC alterFieldSize @column = 'ClientTelephone',    @table = 'Client',  @prsColumnLen = @fieldLen;
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: No need for USE as that is determined in the sqlcmd connection to a specific dB. I have a gut feeling the other errors might get resolved using the keyword GO

Comment: I tried that and it created more errors with the variable declarations, kept saying they werent declared. Or already are declared. I have managed to fix it by commenting out the procedure call. It works without it. So i guess i will just run them seperately.

Comment: And the reason for USE, is because it needs to be run against 3 different databases (pulls data from 2 and puts into another whilst copying ID numbers accross from each)